# C# return multiple columns and rows from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a scenario to query DB for two columns and return all the rows to a different method for further processing. I am not sure if my approach below is the best. Can you please share any better techniques to accomplish this.
The below code works well for a single row returned from SQL.

```
public (Int32 SiteID, string SiteName) QueryDB(string ConnStr)
{
    Int32 SiteID = 0;
    string SiteName = "";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetSiteDetails", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                SiteID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
                SiteName = reader[1].ToString();
            }
        }
    return (SiteID, SiteName);
}
```

In order to address multiple rows result, I am using string concatenated in a List. I believe there must be a better way of doing this because I have an overhead of having to split the string in the list to use the values..

```
public List<string> QueryDB(string ConnStr)
{
    List<string> SiteDetails = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetSiteDetails", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            SiteDetails.Add(reader[0] + "|" + reader[1]);
        }
    }
    return SiteDetails;
}
```

Comment: All ADO.NET tutorials show better ways. For starters, you could load all data into a DataTable. Or you could create strongly typed objects and set their properties to the column values. Or you could create a `List<object>` and add column values to it instead of appending strings. Use an ORM to automagically convert rows to objects, or a microORM like Dapper to do the same with a single line.

Comment: if `reader[0]` or `reader[1]` is unique you can store as dictionary

Comment: Or you can use `reader.GetValues()` to fill an array with all values in a single operation

Comment: Is there any reason for not using class with properties `SiteId and SiteName` instead of two separate variables?

Answer (score 4):

You can return a `List<(int SiteID, string SiteName)>`:

```cs
var list = new List<(int, string)>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var siteID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
    var siteName = reader[1].ToString();
    list.Add((siteID, siteName));
}
return list;
```

However, personally I'd recommend *not* returning value-tuples in public APIs, and returning your own custom type instead - i.e. a `List<SiteInfo>` for a `class SiteInfo` or `readonly struct SiteInfo` that *has* an `int SiteID` and `string SiteName` as properties; i.e.

```cs
public sealed class SiteInfo
{
    public int SiteID {get;set;}
    public string SiteID {get;set;}
}
```

with

```cs
var list = new List<SiteInfo>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var siteID = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
    var siteName = reader[1].ToString();
    list.Add(new SiteInfo { SiteID = siteID, SiteName = siteName });
}
return list;
```

Either way: Dapper could really help you with this!

```cs
public List<(int SiteID, string SiteName)> QueryDB(string ConnStr)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        return con.Query<(int,string)>("spGetSiteDetails",
              commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();
}
```

or

```cs
public List<SiteInfo> QueryDB(string ConnStr)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        return con.Query<SiteInfo>("spGetSiteDetails",
              commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To return a collection you can write:

```
public IEnumerable<(Int32 SiteID, string SiteName)> QueryDB(string ConnStr)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetSiteDetails", con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return (Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]), reader[1].ToString());
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the DataTable which solves the problem straight away

```
dataTable.Load(reader);
```

Comment: Noooooooo..... `DataTable` is almost never the right solution to your problem, unless you're writing an ad-hoc query DSL or reporting UI. For app logic - things where the shape is predictable - literally **anything else** is preferable. `DataTable` was largely a bridge for people migrating from COM ADO RecordSet - from VB6!!!